# How to determine that all the variables in my list are the same to each other in python 3

Tags: python

I am making this program where I am checking if the user gets a yahtzee or not and I want to check if all the variables are the same either 1,2,3,4,5,6 and I don't want to make 6 different lists. Is there any easy way to check?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? (hint: it's fairly trivial, if you can't sort this out by yourself then you're not going to make it in computer programming).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like the following already? 
I.e. essentially if they're all the same then they're also all the same as the first (index 0) element.

```
vals = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
same = all( [ v == vals[0] for v in vals] )
print(same)
```

outputs

```
True
```

while

```
vals = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
same = all( [ v == vals[0] for v in vals] )
print(same)
```

outputs

```
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `set` for this as follows:

```
vals = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

if len(vals) == 6 and len(set(vals)) == 1:
    print "yahtzee"
```

First check for the correct number of values (if required), then convert them to a set. If they are all the same, the length of the set will be 1.

Comment: I don't think there's any real need to check the length of the list first. Presumably, that's fixed by the game.